# how to display N divs in one row

Tags: angularjs

I want my application to display only 9 subdivs/images (with id #menu-entry) in one row which is inside ngReapet. My code is following but **it displays only one entry**.

```
<menu role="main-menu" type="toolbar" class="hidden-xs">
   <div ng-repeat="game in allGames | orderBy: 'gamename'">
        <div id=#row class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" ng-if="($index +1) % 9 == 1">
            <div class="menu-entry">
                <a href="category?game={{game.gameid}}" title="{{game.gamename}}!">
                    <img src="img/icons/{{game.gamename}}_logo.png" alt="Przejdź do działu z {{game.gamename}}!" class="img-responsive" />
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div ng-if="(($index +1) % 9 == 0) || $index == $last "></div>
    </div>
</menu>
```

Hot to fix it to display all menu-entries, 9 in row, displaying as much rows as needed.

Comment: can you setup demo code over jsfiddle OR plukr

Comment: doesn't the ng-if destroy the child as well which is the bit you want? Try closing the containing div before your class="menu-entry" one?

Comment: i think you can use limitTo filter limiting it to 9. `<div ng-repeat="game in allGames | orderBy: 'gamename'" | limitTo: 9>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it in following way but maybe there is shorter version? Maybe ngRepeat inside ngRepeat?

```
<menu role="main-menu" type="toolbar" class="hidden-xs">

    <div ng-repeat="game in allGames | orderBy: 'gamename'">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" ng-if="$index % 9 == 0">

            <div class="menu">
                <a href="category?gameid={{allGames[$index].gameid}}" title="{{allGames[$index].gamename}}!">
                    <img src="img/icons/{{allGames[$index].gamename}}_logo.png" alt="Przejdź do działu z {{allGames[$index].gamename}}!" class="img-responsive" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="menu">
                <a href="category?gameid={{allGames[$index+1].gameid}}" title="{{allGames[$index+1].gamename}}!">
                    <img src="img/icons/{{allGames[$index+1].gamename}}_logo.png" alt="Przejdź do działu z {{allGames[$index+1].gamename}}!" class="img-responsive" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="menu">
                <a href="category?gameid={{allGames[$index+2].gameid}}" title="{{allGames[$index+2].gamename}}!">
                    <img src="img/icons/{{allGames[$index+2].gamename}}_logo.png" alt="Przejdź do działu z {{allGames[$index+2].gamename}}!" class="img-responsive" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="menu">
                <a href="category?gameid={{allGames[$index+3].gameid}}" title="{{allGames[$index+3].gamename}}!">
                    <img src="img/icons/{{allGames[$index+3].gamename}}_logo.png" alt="Przejdź do działu z {{allGames[$index+3].gamename}}!" class="img-responsive" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="menu">
                <a href="category?gameid={{allGames[$index+4].gameid}}" title="{{allGames[$index+4].gamename}}!">
                    <img src="img/icons/{{allGames[$index+4].gamename}}_logo.png" alt="Przejdź do działu z {{allGames[$index+4].gamename}}!" class="img-responsive" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="menu">
                <a href="category?gameid={{allGames[$index+5].gameid}}" title="{{allGames[$index+5].gamename}}!">
                    <img src="img/icons/{{allGames[$index+5].gamename}}_logo.png" alt="Przejdź do działu z {{allGames[$index+5].gamename}}!" class="img-responsive" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="menu">
                <a href="category?gameid={{allGames[$index+6].gameid}}" title="{{allGames[$index+6].gamename}}!">
                    <img src="img/icons/{{allGames[$index+6].gamename}}_logo.png" alt="Przejdź do działu z {{allGames[$index+6].gamename}}!" class="img-responsive" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="menu">
                <a href="category?gameid={{allGames[$index+7].gameid}}" title="{{allGames[$index+7].gamename}}!">
                    <img src="img/icons/{{allGames[$index+7].gamename}}_logo.png" alt="Przejdź do działu z {{allGames[$index+7].gamename}}!" class="img-responsive" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="menu">
                <a href="category?gameid={{allGames[$index+8].gameid}}" title="{{allGames[$index+8].gamename}}!">
                    <img src="img/icons/{{allGames[$index+8].gamename}}_logo.png" alt="Przejdź do działu z {{allGames[$index+8].gamename}}!" class="img-responsive" />
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div ng-init="arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,437,67,436,345,54,1,2,3,4,5,6]"></div>
    <span ng-repeat = "i in arr track by $index">
        <span>{{i}}</span>
        <div ng-if="($index+1)%9==0"></div>
    </span>
```

Even you can use `div` instead of `span` but make sure that

```
<span ng-repeat = "i in arr track by $index">
    <span>{{i}}</span>
```

if you make the above lines to `divs`, their display property should be `inline-block` and

```
<div ng-if="($index+1)%9==0"></div>
```

its display property should be `block` to get 9 `divs` in each row.

https://plnkr.co/edit/Y2cJrUGYcygvM9i6wKx5?p=preview